# How to do a partial look up in excel and get the data in next column till four rows in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I have  **sheet 1** with Column name: Main task

**MainTask**

[image]

And, I have **Sheet 2** where the **Sub-tasks** are given based on the characters between 1st and 2nd hyphen(-) of the **Data in Main Task** for eg: Under the main task column there is "**Pyramid - IoT Forecast - Latin America - Argentina - 2017**". So, based on the string " **IoT Forecast**" the sub tasks are given as in the below image.

[image]

**Out Put:**

Now In sheet 3  I need every title from the main task should be copied and pasted from the Sheet 1 and look for relevant sub tasks and pasted in the next column like the below image.

[image]

I have used, Wild cards, partial V-look up with Mid Function but only single sub task is populating. Please help me provide code in VBA.

Comment: What do you mean "only single sub task is populating"?  Please post the code that isn't working. It is possibly a simple change to correct it but, without seeing the code you are using, we are going to struggle to guess what you are doing wrong.

Comment: `FIND` or `SEARCH` and `SUBSTITUTE`  but you'll need to do as an array I believe.  Is your VLOOKUP being filled down, if so is the main task locked in, or is it looking for blanks?  Your first hyphen would be `=SEARCH("@",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-","@",1),1)` the 2nd `=SEARCH("@",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-","@",2),1)`  Without any code, it's hard to see what you've done, and translate the question into what you want.

Comment: Sir, after I paste the Main task manually in the cell, I have used the  formula ( =VLOOKUP("IoT Forecast*",'Sub Task'!D2:E21,2,0) ) to get the Sub- tasks. But, it is showing only the first sub-task value. I fyou could just the last image in the question You can see four out put( sub tasks) for the main one task, but when I am using formula I am getting only first sub task as " New country forecast model development".

Comment: VLOOKUP only returns one value, I think you'll need an array.

Answer (score 0):

Your Sheet 3 is identical to Sheet 2 but with the full main task in it instead of just the extract. I suggest the following method.

1. Create a column in Sheet 1 in which you write only the extract. This column would be identical in contents to column A of sheet 2. Use this formula to populate that column (where A2 contains the full main task).

   =TRIM(LEFT(MID($A2,FIND("-",$A2)+1,100),FIND("-",MID($A2,FIND("-",$A2)+1,100))-1))
2. Make a copy of Sheet 2 as Sheet 3 and add a blank column B in it. Populate this column with this formula (where A:A is the column containing the full task, and C:C the column you added in step 1.

   =INDEX('Sheet 1'!A:A,MATCH(A2,'Sheet 1'!C:C,0))
3. Replace the formulas in Sheet 3 with values (Copy / Paste values) and Remove column A from that sheet. Sort this sheet on what is now column A.
4. Remove the column you added in Sheet 1 to restore Sheet 1 to its original state.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do an array formula, something similar to the below where the sub category is in C1

`=INDEX($A$2:$A$6,SMALL(IF(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("-" & $C$1 & "-",$A$2:$A$6))),ROW($A$2:$A$6)-1),ROWS($D$1:D1)))`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to a VBA solution, you may try something like this.
The following code assumes that there are three sheets in the workbook named as "Sheet1", "Sheet2" and "Sheet3".

If the sheet names are different in your original workbook, please change them in the code in following lines before testing the code.

```
Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
Set ws3 = Sheets("Sheet3")
```

Place the following code on a Standard Module and run the code to get the desired output on Sheet3.

```
Sub LookupData()
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, ws3 As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range, MainTask As Range
Dim lr2 As Long, lr3 As Long
Dim MainTaskStr As String, wht As String
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
Set ws3 = Sheets("Sheet3")
lr2 = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = ws2.Range("A2:A" & lr2)

ws3.Cells.Clear
ws3.Range("A1:B1").Value = Array("Main Task", "Sub-Task")

If ws2.FilterMode Then ws2.ShowAllData

For Each cell In rng
    If cell.Value <> MainTaskStr Then
        MainTaskStr = cell.Value
        lr3 = ws3.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row + 1
        wht = "- " & cell.Value & " -"
        Set MainTask = ws1.Range("A:A").Find(what:=wht, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)
        If Not MainTask Is Nothing Then
            With ws2.Rows(1)
                .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=MainTaskStr
                ws3.Range("A" & lr3) = MainTask.Value
                ws2.Range("B2:B" & lr2).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy ws3.Range("B" & lr3)
            End With
        End If
    End If
Next cell

If ws2.FilterMode Then ws2.AutoFilterMode = False

ws3.UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```